# How can I translate the managed models tabs?

Tags: silverstripe

In my Silverstripe module I use $managed_models to create tabs on the right top, see here:

[image]

My code:

```
private static $managed_models = array(
    'HomeRental',
    'City',
    'HomeType'
);
```

How can I translate the name of this tabs? I use the Silverstripe-translate module as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by translating the model's `$singular_name` value.

In your */module/lang/de.yml* e.g.:

```
de:
  GalleryPic:
    PLURALNAME: Galeriebilder
    SINGULARNAME: Galeriebild #translated singularname
    db_Copyright: Copyright 
    has_one_Attachment: Anhang
```

You can even translate $db and $has_one fieldnames by prefixing the fieldname with `db_` and `has_one_` `has_many_` and `many_many_`

[Zauberfisch's BetterI18N](https://github.com/Zauberfisch/silverstripe-better-i18n) module will help you whith an improved `I18NTextcollectorTask` that will collect all values for you and generates a yml file with all standard variables you need to translate your code.

IMHO it's useful to use english values in the code and templates directly (even if you develop in another language), grab all values with the TextcollectorTask and translate the yml files.